# interface gazebo camera with c++ program

Tags: gazebo, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how can i interface camera in gazebo which publish image topic , to non ros c++ program which take its input from usb web cam ?

can i make a node to convert the ros topic to fake usb cam or what please help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232620/interface-gazebo-camera-with-c++-program/) by [g-emad](https://answers.ros.org/users/26155/g-emad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2016-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See http://answers.ros.org/question/215325/can-we-publish-image-topic-from-ros-to-a-virtual-video-device/

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2